# normalize and serialize json

Tags: php, json, serialization, normalization

have json array contain nested arrays the goal in to be serialized

> Pseudo Code Implementation

```
function string Serialize(documentStructure)
    
    if documentStructure is simple value type
        return """ + documentStructure.value + """
    end if

    var serializedString = ""
    
    foreach element in the structure:
        
        if element is not array type
            serializeString.Append (""" + element.name.uppercase + """)
            serializeString.Append ( Serialize(element.value) )
        end if

        if element is of array type
            serializeString.Append (""" + element.name.uppercase + """)
            foreach array element in element: 
                // use below line for JSON because subelements of array in JSON do not have own names
                serializeString.Append (""" + element.name.uppercase + """)         
                serializeString.Append ( Serialize(arrayelement.value) )              
            end foreach
        end if

    end foreach

    return serializedString
end function
```

Serialize and normalize receipt object and flatten all its properties in one line text.
Create a hash value of the normalized text using SHA256.
Convert the hash value from array of 32 bytes to hexadecimal string of 64 characters.
Use the hexadecimal string as receipt UUID.

foreach loop

```
function zoza($arr)
{
    

    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            echo '"' . $key . '"';
            zoza($val);
        } else {
           echo  '"' . $key . '"' . '"' . $val . '"');
        }
    }
    
    return $names ;
}

$zoza($maArray)
```

its print exact needs but cant get it to variable to hash it

Comment: `return $names ;` - what `$names`? There is no such variable in the scope of your function. Maybe you want to _append_ to a string variable, instead of writing to the output buffer directly here ...?

Comment: I mean, it's basically already in your pseudo-code ... you just need to _properly_ translate that into PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I’m understanding you correctly, you just need to concatenate inside of the function and return that.

```php
function zoza($arr)
{
    $names = '';
    foreach ($arr as $key => $val) {
        if (is_array($val)) {
            $names .= '"' . $key . '"';
            $names .= zoza($val);
        } else {
           $names .= '"' . $key . '"' . '"' . $val . '"';
        }
    }
    
    return $names ;
}

$data = [
        'a' => 'test',
        'b' => [
            [
                ['something']
            ]
        ]
    ];
    
$s = zoza($data);

$h = hash('sha256', $s, false);

echo $s, PHP_EOL, $h;

// Output:
// "a""test""b""0""0""0""something"
// 72597037bd2c14df0e4580cf79f83aed0657987cabd6f1f5968bc59dad634072
```

Demo: https://3v4l.org/i21RZ

Comment: Although having written that, I wouldn’t call this “normalization” in any way. That would be making sure that data is in a consistent order which your code isn’t doing. Since you aren’t doing that, just `json_encode` the array which will give you a string which you can then hash.